# Getting a max date using various groups in a select in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Been stuck on this. I have the query and the result set below:

```
DECLARE @bookdate date = cast(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), - 1) AS DATE)
DECLARE @offset int = 1

SELECT distinct @bookdate BookDate
    ,th.Transactioncd TransactionType
    ,bp.PolicyNumber PolicyNumber
    ,cast(bp.EffectiveDt AS DATE) EffectiveDate
    ,cast(th.TransactionEffectiveDt AS DATE) TransactionEffectiveDate
    ,NULL
    ,th.TransactionNumber TransactionNumber
    ,cast(bp.ExpirationDt AS DATE) ExpirationDate
    ,UPPER(ni.IndexName) InsuredName
    ,isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr1), '') + ' ' + isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr2), '') + ' ' + isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr3), '') + ' ' + isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr4), '') InsuredStreetAddress
    ,UPPER(ad.City) InsuredCity
    ,UPPER(ad.StateProvCd) InsuredState
    ,ad.PostalCode InsuredZipCode
    ,i.EntityTypeCd InsuredType
    ,isnull(tr.ReasonCd, '') ReasonCode
    ,cast(datediff(mm, th.transactioneffectivedt, bp.expirationdt) / cast(datediff(mm, bp.effectivedt, bp.expirationdt) AS DECIMAL(15, 4)) AS DECIMAL(15, 4)) ProrateFactor
    ,'0'
    ,'0'
    ,'0'
    ,bd.YearBuilt YrConstruction
    ,ln.PROPDed + '%' [% loss ded EQ]
    ,CAST(bd.BldgNumber AS VARCHAR(255)) BldgNumber
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.BuildingValue,',','')) BuildingValue
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.ContentsBLimit,',','')) ContentsBLimit
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.ContentsCLimit,',','')) ContentsCLimit
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.TIBLimit,',','')) TIBLimit
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.BILimit,',','')) BILimit
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.EDPLimit,',','')) EDPLimit
FROM java.basicpolicy bp
INNER JOIN java.nameinfo ni ON ni.SystemId = bp.SystemId
    AND ni.CMMContainer = bp.CMMContainer
INNER JOIN java.partyinfo pti on pti.Id=ni.ParentId
    AND pti.CMMContainer=bp.CMMContainer
    and pti.SystemId=bp.SystemId
INNER JOIN java.line ln ON ln.CMMContainer = bp.CMMContainer
    AND bp.SystemId = ln.SystemId
INNER JOIN java.risk r on r.SystemId=bp.SystemId
    AND r.CMMContainer=bp.CMMContainer
    AND r.ParentId=ln.Id
INNER JOIN java.building bd ON bd.CMMContainer = bp.CMMContainer
    AND bd.SystemId = bp.SystemId
    AND bd.ParentId=r.id
    AND bd.[Status] = 'ACTIVE'
INNER JOIN java.addr ad ON ad.CMMContainer = ni.CMMContainer
    AND bp.SystemId = ad.SystemId
    AND ad.AddrTypeCd in ('RiskAddr')
    AND ad.ParentId = bd.id
INNER JOIN java.transactioninfo th ON th.CMMContainer = bp.CMMContainer
    AND th.SystemId = bp.SystemId
LEFT JOIN java.transactionreason tr ON tr.CMMContainer = bp.CMMContainer
    AND TR.SystemId = bp.SystemId
    AND TR.ParentId = th.ID
INNER JOIN java.insured i ON i.CMMContainer = bp.CMMContainer
    AND i.SystemId = bp.SystemId
WHERE bp.CMMContainer = 'Application'
    AND ni.NameTypeCd = 'INSUREDNAME'
    AND (
        th.TransactionCd IN (
            'new business'
            ,'endorsement'
            ,'cancellation'
            ,'rewrite-new'
            )
        OR (
            th.WrittenPremiumAmt IS NOT NULL
            AND th.WrittenPremiumAmt <> 0
            AND th.TransactionCd IN ('reinstatement')
            )
        )
    AND bp.CarrierCd = 'ENIC'
    AND th.TransactionEffectiveDt not like '2016-12%'
GROUP BY
    th.Transactioncd
    ,bp.PolicyNumber
    ,cast(bp.EffectiveDt AS DATE) 
    ,cast(th.TransactionEffectiveDt AS DATE)
    ,th.TransactionNumber
    ,cast(bp.ExpirationDt AS DATE) 
    ,UPPER(ni.IndexName) 
    ,isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr1), '') + ' ' + isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr2), '') + ' ' + isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr3), '') + ' ' + isnull(UPPER(ad.Addr4), '') 
    ,UPPER(ad.City) 
    ,UPPER(ad.StateProvCd) 
    ,ad.PostalCode 
    ,i.EntityTypeCd 
    ,isnull(tr.ReasonCd, '') 
    ,cast(datediff(mm, th.transactioneffectivedt, bp.expirationdt) / cast(datediff(mm, bp.effectivedt, bp.expirationdt) AS DECIMAL(15, 4)) AS DECIMAL(15, 4)) 
    ,bd.YearBuilt
    ,ln.PROPDed + '%' 
    ,CAST(bd.BldgNumber AS VARCHAR(255)) 
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.BuildingValue,',','')) 
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.ContentsBLimit,',','')) 
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.ContentsCLimit,',','')) 
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.TIBLimit,',','')) 
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.BILimit,',','')) 
    ,CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(bd.EDPLimit,',','')) 
ORDER BY PolicyNumber, transactionnumber, bldgnumber
```

I get this result set:

[image]

What I want is to remove the duplicated transaction number 2 as you can see on the picture. I tried doing the max and group by function using the date and it didn't work. I tried it on transaction number, it works but introduced other problems. Is there anyway that I can get one result set? It is not a real duplicate, it has a different date but I only want to get the latest date that's why I figured the max function might work but I have to group by everything and that didn't help much. I have been looking at outer apply but I have never used that and I don't even know how I would use that on this particular problem.

Comment: I think you are on the right track using the MAX function on the Transaction Effective Date field. Yes, you will need to use a group by for all of the other fields. Do that and you should be good.

Comment: I thought max and group by would work but since I am grouping by everything except for the maximum value of the date, it would still return two values since they there are different dates I believe.

Comment: You should only get a single row back (from those 2 rows of input) with the maximum transaction effective date.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first_value?

```
FIRST_VALUE ( [scalar_expression ] )   
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause [ rows_range_clause ] )
```

it works like this: you need to write **DISTINCT**

```
  select **distinct** id, 
         first_value(transaction_effective_date) over (partition by number (,sup) order by date DESC (latest, ASC for oldest)) as last_trans_date
 from table;
```

Documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx

Comment: Oh I am using SQL Server 2008 and it looks like this only applies to 2012 and above :(